# Order of execution inside go routines

Tags: concurrency, go, goroutine

I recently started with go and I am really confused about the order of execution of this program. I hope I am not asking really trivial questions here.

This is basically #69 in the golang tour, with some Println I have inserted; Link to playground: http://play.golang.org/p/PXDlD3EA2f

```
func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1

    fmt.Println("Inside the fibonacci")

    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            fmt.Println("Inside the for, first case, before reassigning ", x, y)
            x, y = y, x+y
            fmt.Println("Inside the for, first case, after reassigning ", x, y)
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Begin of Main")
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    fmt.Println("Before gonig to the func")
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Inside go routine")
        fmt.Println("Inside go routine... again")
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println("Inside go routine and the for, before printing the channel")
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fmt.Println("Before calling to fibonacci")
    fibonacci(c, quit)
    fmt.Println("Closing")
}
```

In the very verbose output I obtain (see attached image below), there are a couple of things I do not understand:

- why is the "Inside the fibonacci" line before the ones in the go routine? Is this because after the  go command, the compiler is just reading *at the same time* inside func and fibonacci?
- how do fibonacci and func interact? func is not changing the channel c, so why is fibonacci reacting? Who's changing c?
- why inside fibonacci there are 5 prints together every time? Honesty I was expecting only 2.

Output of the function:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take it step by step:

### * **why is the "Inside the fibonacci" line before the ones in the go routine? Is this because after the go command, the compiler is just reading at the same time inside func and fibonacci?**

Because your go routine actually starts after you call `fibonacci`, the scheduler takes a little bit of time to start, for example if you start a goroutine that calls `fmt.Println` and do nothing to wait in `main`, the program will exit before it gets executed.

### * **how do fibonacci and func interact? func is not changing the channel c, so why is fibonacci reacting? Who's changing c?**

`fibonacci` is pushing numbers into the channel, notice this part:

```
select {
        case c <- x: //this is sending x to the channel
```

### * **why inside fibonacci there are 5 prints together every time? Honesty I was expecting only 2.**

That again depends on the scheduler and the fact that `fmt.Print*` doesn't lock stdout, the output can happen in any order since it's 2 different threads printing stuff.

Comment: The playground is running with `GOMAXPROCS=1`, one OS thread, so I'd phrase this not in therms of scheduler "taking time" and "threads" and lack of locking, but the scheduler getting to arbitrarily choose between the goroutines as long as both are runnable (in this case, until one blocks on a channel send or receive). May try to compose that into an answer, but that's some work. :P

Comment: Thanks @OneOfOne this makes things a little clearer, but I have a follow up question. Since it is fibonacci that changes c, basically func asks fibonacci for 10 different values of x, and then exits fibonacci via the quit channel?

Comment: @meto yep exactly, fibonacci will keep writing to that channel forever or until someone writes something to the quit channel, which what your other function does after reading 1 values.

Comment: @OneOfOne thanks. This works because the channel is not buffered, right? Otherwise fibonacci would continue to write on the channel before waiting for func to read it / empty the channel?

Comment: @meto that is correct, however once fibonacci quits the channel will still have some values in it if it was buffered.

Comment: Thanks @OneOfOne you have really been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but i found this presentation very handy to understand how channels work: [Google I/O 2012 - Go Concurrency Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs)
In here you find answers for your questions.